# What's a typical ElasticSearch/Logstash/Kibana deployment model look like

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

Being a novice to docker/elastic search worlds, I am trying to build a deployment model of using elastic search via containers in one of my project.
I have few application servers, each of which have some logs. I would like to have all these logs at one place. Below is what I have in my mind.

All application servers install filebeat to push data to a Logstash server (in a docker image). This LogStash server forward these logs to elasticsearch docker image that also have kibana.

Does this make sense? Is it OK to have logstash in one image and ElasticSearch/Kibana on a different one? Are there any pros/cons of this approach? What could be alternative approaches to architect this?

Comment: We have an example for getting the entire Elastic stack up and running with Docker here https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The policy of Docker is that 1 container does 1 thing and 1 thing good. So I would go for a docker image for ElasticSearch, 1 for Kibana and one for LogStash. Add them together with docker compose.

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#use-multi-stage-builds

> **Each container should have only one concern**
>
> Decoupling applications into multiple containers makes it much easier to scale horizontally and reuse containers. For instance, a web application stack might consist of three separate containers, each with its own unique image, to manage the web application, database, and an in-memory cache in a decoupled manner.
>
> You may have heard that there should be “one process per container”. While this mantra has good intentions, it is not necessarily true that there should be only one operating system process per container. In addition to the fact that containers can now be spawned with an init process, some programs might spawn additional processes of their own accord. For instance, Celery can spawn multiple worker processes, or Apache might create a process per request. While “one process per container” is frequently a good rule of thumb, it is not a hard and fast rule. Use your best judgment to keep containers as clean and modular as possible.
>
> If containers depend on each other, you can use Docker container networks to ensure that these containers can communicate.

Comment: Edited my answer to add the link to the one concern